How do respond to BOOTP requests using the TFTP daemon with Fedora?
I'm trying to boot a few embedded machines over an RNDIS network link (USB) and I can't seem to get the TFTP server daemon to respond to the BOOTP requests. I can see the BOOTP request packet being received over the link but the daemon doesn't respond with anything. I can't even confirm that the TFTP server is receiving the packet... for all I know, it could be blocked by an incorrect routing table or something.
I did get this working with DHCP but I haven't had any luck with the TFTP server daemon.
(I'm kind of a newb when it comes to debugging and tracing packets throughout the kernel so any help with locating the issue would be appreciated :)  )

Edit: TFTP 5.2 HPA doesn't handle BOOTP requests. Trying dhcpcd


Which TFTP server, and how do you know that it is supposed to answer BOOTP?

Good thing you asked. It was TFTP 5.2 HPA and it looks like it does not contain code to handle BOOTP requests. I'll give dhdpcd another try. Thanks.


It was TFTP 5.2 HPA

The short answer is that you don't respond to BOOTP requests using the TFTP daemon, because they are two different protocols that have no overlap, and are traditionally handled by separate servers (even running on different machines).
While there do exist "all-in-one" server programs that serve both Bootp+TFTP or DHCP+TFTP from a single service (Dnsmasq being a popular one), that's not the case in general, and the tftpd-hpa software is purely a TFTP server and does not deal with DHCP or BOOTP at all. You'll need either a separate DHCP/Bootp server, or replace tftpd-hpa with Dnsmasq.
